# Why does a null state correspond to a field that any correlator containing it vanishes?

Tags: hilbert-space, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

I am reading the 7th chapter of Di Francesco's CFT book. It builds, for example in section 7.3, a null state $|x>$ which is orthogonal to the whole Verma Module. The author asserts that the field $x$ representing the state has the property that any correlation function containing the field $x$ vanishes, which the author does not provide the reader with a justification.

Now I am confused by the assertion. Why is the assertion true? Can anyone give me an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

The two-point functions of the null state $N(z,\bar z)$ with an operator $O(z,\bar z)$ is proportional to the inner product of the corresponding states $\langle n| o\rangle $, so it vanishes. The three-point and higher-point functions $NOP\cdots $ vanish as well because the products $OP\cdots $ may be expanded, using OPEs, in terms of "single operators", and that is how the correlator is reduced to the two-point function.

Comment: Thanks Luboš Motl. I was just struggling over why the two point functions vanish.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on this? Why does $\langle n|o \rangle$ vanish?

Comment: It is just the basic state operator correspondence. States are equivalent to operators and the inner products of these states are equivalent to two point functions of the operators. This is surely covered earlier in the book because it is basic stuff about conformal field theories.

Answer (score 1):

Luboš Motl's answer and comment are almost complete, but let me make it more clear. In the following, I just write the chiral part.

The inner product of two highest weight states (not null) is $\langle h|h'\rangle=\delta_{h,h'}=\langle0|\phi^{\dagger}_{h}(0)\phi_{h'}(0)|0\rangle$.

While the two-point function $\langle0|\phi_h(z)\phi_{h'}(0)|0\rangle = \frac{\delta_{h,h'}}{z^{2h}}=\frac{\langle h|h'\rangle}{z^{2h}}$.

Now: $\langle0|\chi(z)X|0\rangle=\sum\mathcal{L}_i\langle0|\chi(z)\phi_{h_i}(w_i)|0\rangle$ where we have used OPE to turn the correlation function to 2-point correlation function. If $\chi(z)$ as a primary field has a different conformal dimension from $\phi_{h_i}(w)$, then that 2-point correlation function vanishes. If $\chi(z)$ as a primary field has the same conformal dimension as $\phi_{h_i}(w)$, we can further consider $\chi(z)$ as a descendant of some primary field $\phi_{h_0}(z)$, and the $h_0$ is definitely different from $h_i$, so the two-point correlation function again. So  $\langle0|\chi(z)X|0\rangle=0$ holds all the time.

We also learn from this that  $\langle0|\phi_h(z)\phi_{h'}(0)|0\rangle = 
\frac{\langle h|h'\rangle}{z^{2h}}$ holds all the time, no matter $\phi_h(z)$ is a null (primary) field or normal primary field. Since a null state is orthogonal to all the states in the Hilbert space.